# Is there a way to switch from fullscreen to windowed mode in Neverwinter Nights in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, neverwinter-nights

I've decided to start playing *Neverwinter Nights* again and I was wondering if there is a keystroke to toggle from fullscreen to windowed mode (such as if I hit <kbd>⌘M</kbd> or <kbd>⌘Tab</kbd> in *Warcraft III* or *StarCraft*).

I've tried the instructions on the [*NWN* Wikia](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Window_mode) and while it does put the game in windowed mode, I can't find any equivalent key combo to switch between the two.

My ideal is to be able to run the game fullscreen at my laptop's native resolution and be able to switch to windowed mode (at any other resolution) without having to restart the game.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can do this, as a friend of mine (who also has a Mac) wanted to be able to switch between windowed and full-screen.

While on Windows is <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>, there is nothing for Mac.